# Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available

Tags: java, hibernate, entitymanager, transactional

An exception occurs while I'm trying to persist an object.

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository("DBRepository")
@Transactional
public class DBRepository implements Repository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void addElement(Element element) {
        logger.debug("Element {} is going to be added to database", element);
        entityManager.persist(element);
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="p_unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"/>

</persistence>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/jpa-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

jpa-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Using annotation to configure application -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="web.tmh"/>

    <!-- Tells Spring to use persistence context annotation -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="p_unit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <!-- autoReconnect=true param allows our application to reconnect to base if connection was lost -->
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TellMeHow?autoReconnect=true"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

So as you can see I used right Transactional annotation, and have `<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>`in my jpa-config.xml. So I don't really understand why it doesn't want do work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was solved. I've made a small mistake in my `dispatcher-config.xml`:

So instead of

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="web.tmh"/>
```

I had to write

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="web.tmh.controller"/>
```

I thought that `component-scan` worked recursively, but seems like it didn't...

Comment: The fix is right. The root cause is a little bit more complex than it seems. You were scanning the same packages in two contexts (the dispatcher servlet config, and the JPA config) where the first one doesn't take into account transactions. Because of the servlet context scanning, an instance of your repository without transaction support was found and injected, so the transaction wasn't in progress when you tried to save your object. For more detail, see this excellent answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28950767