# Facing a issue related to hibernate "javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException"

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hi when i am trying to deploy MY WAR FILE on server i successfully able to deploy ,but after that my application is working fine burt in server a got a error

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in
>   progress  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3466)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1426)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1422)
>     at com.mcd.aag.dao.impl.AAGDAOImpl.insertAAGForm(AAGDAOImpl.java:70)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.insertAAGForm(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.mcd.aag.service.impl.AAGServiceImpl.insertFormOne(AAGServiceImpl.java:68)
>     at
>   com.mcd.aag.controller.AAGApplicationController.updateAAGFormOne(AAGApplicationController.java:245)
>     at
>   com.mcd.aag.controller.AAGApplicationController.insertUpdateAAGFormOne(AAGApplicationController.java:166)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:802)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

plz help i stuck on this from last 5 days

Comment: Please show us your code so we have more info to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `@Transactional` on your method.

You should introduce your entity manager to your transaction manager, so that when you annotate your function with `@Transactional`it loads instances from the pool

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

If above doesnt work refer below thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28950767/6572971